# What did Dr. Arden say before attempting suicide in AHS S02E10?

Tags: character, dialogue, american-horror-story

In American Horror Story: Asylum episode 10, Dr. Arden kills the Raspers and tries to shoot himself too, which he failed to do. But before the suicide attempt he said something, which was not in English. What did he say and what does it signify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He says "Finita la commedia" - which is an Italian phrase and means: "The farce is over" or "The play is over" (the time where he says it is around 20:00 minutes for anyone who wants to hear it).

> “La commedia è finita!” (The play is over!) is the final line in the opera “Pagliacci”, uttered by the character of Canio after he stabs and kills his wife Nedda and her lover Silvio on the stage of the play that all three of them were acting in.
>
> It has remained a popular saying in Italy and abroad when a sad affair comes to a tragic end.

Source for the quote from here: https://finitolacommedia.wordpress.com/what-is-finito-la-commedia/

You can read more about the play here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagliacci

> Nedda, trying to continue the play, admits that she has been visited by the innocent Arlecchino. Canio, furious and forgetting the play, demands the name of her lover. Nedda swears she will never tell him, and the crowd realizes they are not acting. Silvio begins to fight his way toward the stage. Canio, grabbing a knife from the table, stabs Nedda. As she dies she calls: "Help! Silvio!". Silvio attacks Canio, but Canio kills Silvio also. The horrified audience then hears the celebrated final line:
>
> La commedia è finita! – "The comedy is finished!"

Comment: Indeed (he even precedes this phrase with the words "it's a farce"), but it might be worth noting that like the protagonist of Pagliacci, Arden felt betrayed by Mary Eunice and that he 'lost' her.